# Is it possible to query a nested field with a collection group query?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried running the query below within Cloud Functions and keep getting an error when I run it. I'm assuming this is because collection group queries don't allow for nested fields in where conditions.

```
const result = db.collectionGroup("recents").where("sound.id", "==", id).get()
```

Here's the error when I run the query:

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:357:73)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

If it is possible to do this, would like to know how, thanks!

Comment: Nested field queries don't work any differently for collection groups. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_collection_group_indexes) for details.  Please edit the question to show the error message so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the error in the edit

Comment: Please edit your question to show a representative document that you'd expect this query to return, so including the `sound.id` value that you match on.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add the collection group indexes in order for my query to work. Once I added those the queries fired as expected and I no longer got the errors.